# Drawpath between two geopoint with image from resource

Tags: android, maps, draw

I need show line between two geopoint but not just line i need use one image from resourse (R.drawable.line_image). Well i can draw line or path just i dont know how i use with image. (I found lot of example, but all use just normal line, not with image)

Sombody little help or example like this? thx

my actualy drawline code:

```
Paint paint;
   paint = new Paint();
   paint.setAntiAlias(true);
   paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
   paint.setStrokeWidth(7);
   Point pt1 = new Point();
   Point pt2 = new Point();
   Projection projection = (Projection) mapView.getProjection();

   projection.toPixels(start_, pt1);
   projection.toPixels(end_, pt2);
   canvas.drawLine(pt1.x, pt1.y, pt2.x, pt2.y, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end i found the solution:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

   Point pt1 = new Point();
   Point pt2 = new Point();
   Projection projection = (Projection) mapView.getProjection();
   projection.toPixels(start_, pt1);
   projection.toPixels(end_, pt2);
   Path mPath = new Path();
   mPath.moveTo(pt2.x,pt2.y);
   mPath.lineTo(pt1.x, pt1.y);
   drawBitmapAlongPath(mPath, bitmap, canvas);
}

void drawBitmapAlongPath(Path p, Bitmap b, Canvas c) {
     Matrix m = new Matrix();
     PathMeasure meas = new PathMeasure(p, false);
     final float length = meas.getLength();
     final float advance = b.getWidth();   
     float distance = 0;
     final int flags = PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG |  
             PathMeasure.TANGENT_MATRIX_FLAG;

     while (distance < length) {
         meas.getMatrix(distance, m, flags);
         c.drawBitmap(b, m, null);
         distance += advance;
     }
}
```